# Custom ListView - Custom Argument

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I'm creating an app for a bus station, to give the schedule. For that i'm using a custom listview. Here it is:

```
class custom_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

public custom_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> horarios) {
    super(context, R.layout.costum_listview ,horarios);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater horarioInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View costumView = horarioInflater.inflate(R.layout.costum_listview, parent, false);

    String singleHorario = getItem(position);
    TextView hora = (TextView) costumView.findViewById(R.id.Hora);
    TextView nota = (TextView) costumView.findViewById(R.id.Nota);

    hora.setText(singleHorario);
    nota.setText(" ");

    return costumView;
}
```

}

Now as you can see I have just 2 texViews yet, the "hora" is to show the timers of the bus, the "nota" is for some notes, like someday the bus don't go or something like that. And my problem is exactly on that "nota" textview. I have dozens of arrayList's passing to this custom ListView, and so dozens and dozens of timers, and there are some timers that I need to put a note and other that I don't. So, can I had another argument to this custom ListView, like a boolean or something, so I can do a if / else in that code to put a note on each one. What do I need to change in order to do that ? I've been trying, but didn't quite managed to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a String as the argument for your ArrayAdapter, create a custom class and use that instead.
That way you can pass all the information you want into the adapter and show it however you like.

```
public class custom_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyClass>{

public custom_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyClass> horarios) {
    super(context, R.layout.costum_listview ,horarios);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater horarioInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View costumView = horarioInflater.inflate(R.layout.costum_listview, parent, false);

    MyClass singleHorario = getItem(position);
    TextView hora = (TextView) costumView.findViewById(R.id.Hora);
    TextView nota = (TextView) costumView.findViewById(R.id.Nota);

    hora.setText(singleHorario.hora);
    nota.setText(singleHorario.nota);

    return costumView;
}
```

And the new class

```
public class MyClass {
    public String hora;
    public String nota;
}
```

Comment: But the problem is, if i had to pass a class, the class would have to have the ArrayList on it, but the "nota" i want to put is not a single note to the all Array, it's a note that i put (or not) in every single item of the array. Don't know if i can explain better. Each item of the Array that i'm passing as to be checked if i want to put a note or not.

Answer (score 0):

How about making a class for holding two values 'hora' and 'nota', and with, lets say, boolean isNotaAvailable() method. Then in getView() you just make something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater horarioInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
View costumView = horarioInflater.inflate(R.layout.costum_listview, parent, false);

YourClassName singleHorario = getItem(position);
TextView hora = (TextView) costumView.findViewById(R.id.Hora);
TextView nota = (TextView) costumView.findViewById(R.id.Nota);
// set hora text 
hora.setText(singleHorario);
// check if nota is available, if true - set nota text
if(singleHorario.isNotaAvailable()) {
nota.setText(singleHorario.getNota())}
else nota.setVisibility(View.GONE);

return costumView;
}
```

It's just an idea, tell me if it helps :)

Comment: But the problem is, if i had to pass a class, the class would have to have the ArrayList on it, but the "nota" i want to put is not a single note to the all Array, it's a note that i put (or not) in every single item of the array. Don't know if i can explain better. Each item of the Array that i'm passing as to be checked if i want to put a note or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just extend `BaseAdapter`, so you can define the data structure.

```
class custom_adapter extends BaseAdapter
```

change `ArrayList<String> horarios` to `ArrayList<Data> horarios`
And the `Data` can be

```
public class Data{
    private String hora;
    private String nota;
    private boolean shouldShowNota;

    //write getter and setter here 
}
```

at last, read the data in `getView`

```
Data data = getItem(position);
if (data.getShouldShowNota) {
    nota.setText(data.getNote);
}
hora.setText(data.getHora);
```

Comment: But the problem is, if i had to pass a class, the class would have to have the ArrayList on it, but the "nota" i want to put is not a single note to the all Array, it's a note that i put (or not) in every single item of the array. Don't know if i can explain better. Each item of the Array that i'm passing as to be checked if i want to put a note or not.